# Flutter - Using Column in pdf package to create multipage pdf gives : Unhandled Exception: Instance of 'TooManyPagesException'

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf, pdf-generation

I am using pdf flutter package to create multipage pdf. I have used wrap widget as parent so that it should wrap all children to available space. But using column gives me error:
Unhandled Exception: Instance of 'TooManyPagesException'
My pdf designs contains two or more columns and many rows. Rows can be handled using pw.Partition but I haven't find the replacement of Column widget.

I want my pdf to be on multipage and there should not any flex or Too Many pages exceptions. Also I want to use Column in my design.

Comment: Can you give some Code snippet

Answer (score -1):

ashraf, if you want someone to help you please do post a link to the Flutter package you are using and also your code so we can see what you might have done wrong. :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).